# I have a text "abcdef". I want to print "bcd". Can you give me some methods?

Tags: shell

I stuck with my problem. I have remember we have command 'mid'. Can you help me

Comment: please share what you tried?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which shell you areusing and what you have tried please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract parts of a string in shell, you can use cut

```
echo "abcdef" | cut -c2-4
```

-c specifies the list of character positions. here, 2-4 indicates position 2 through 4.

Comment: oh nice BlackPearl. I try your method and get the correctly result. Tks you very much for your help